# ZF2 How to add new folder in src Folder except regular folders

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This is the normal folder structure for src folder:

```
src/
    AplicationFolder/
        Model/
        Controller/
        Entity/
        Document/
        Form/
```

So i need to add new folder next to the Form folder, Do I will have to add extra configuration related to class map.

My autoload config as follows:

```
'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
```

Here is `getAutoloaderConfig()` configuration code:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig(){
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you using the classmap autoloader for this module? If no, you don't need to do any special configuration.

Comment: @ Tim Fountain,
Thanks for replying. 

Yes I am using a classmap autoloader. so can you please be kind enough to let me know the configurations

Comment: Can you add your autoloader configuration to your question?

Comment: You mean this  ?

'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),

Comment: In `src/Module.php` you should have a method called `getAutoloaderConfig()`, that's what I want to see.

Comment: Ok here it is. I have update the question also. please check it.

public function getAutoloaderConfig(){
  return array(
   'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
    __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
   ),
   'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
    'namespaces' => array(
     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
    ),
   ),
  );
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using both autoloaders, you don't need to do anything, the standard autoloader should handle any files you add. However, when you're ready to move your app to production, you can regenerate the classmap file (for improved performance) using the provided classmap generator (should be in your vendor folder if you installed ZF with composer).

Cd to your module folder (the one with `Module.php` in), and then run:

```
php ../../vendor/bin/classmap_generator.php
```

Comment: @ Tim

Thank You Tim.